# Kubernetes Cluster created on aws with Kops using weave network is very slow within cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

We have set up two Kubernetes clusters  on aws one using the the [kube-up](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/aws/#kube-up-bash-script) script and other with the [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) create cluster command. We find that the inter-pod communication in the kops created cluster is very slow making us think  the routing is at problem. If anyone has experienced this issue  and have as solution to suggest to reduce the latency its much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. How did you measure slowness? Could you show the output of `kubectl get pods --all-namesapces` ? In general when asking questions you might want to check the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide to raise your chance of getting good answers around here.

Comment: [get po](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8cNohkFzlE7UFFuemtLajJzUE0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: added the link to get po --allnamespaces